# Cluster Analysis in R on large sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a transaction dataset with  250000 transactions (rows) and 2183 items (columns). I wanna transform it to a sparse matrix and then do hierarchical cluster on it. I tried package 'sparcl', but it seems it doesn't work on sparse matrix. Any suggestion about how to solve this problem? Or any other package I can use to do cluster analysis on sparse matrix?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Affinity propagation, as implemented in the apcluster package, supports sparse matrices since version 1.4.0. So please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Would [affinity propagation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apcluster/index.html) work with your data?  It appears to handle sparse matrices.