# affinity propagation clustering on a large sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix

I am trying R package `apcluster` on a set of objects that I want to cluster, but I'm running into performance/memory problems, and I suspect I'm not doing it right. I'd like to hear your opinion, please.

In short: I have a set of about 13000 objects. Each object is associated with a set of 2 to 5 'features'. The similarity (by which I want to cluster, eventually) between any two objects i and j is equal to the number of features they have in common divided by the total number of distinct features they 'span'. E.g. if i = {a,b,c} and j = {c,d}, then sim[i,j] = 1/4 = 0.25, because they have only 1 feature in common ({c}) and in total they describe 4 distinct features ({a,b,c,d}).

Calculating my NxN similarity matrix is not a problem *in theory*: it can be done using set operations if each object's features are stored as a list; or features can be pivoted to a matrix of 1's and 0's, where each column is a feature, and then R's function `dist` with `method="binary"` does the trick.

*In practice* however, the first problem is that such similarity calculations are extremely slow. For 13 K objects, there are about 84.5 M similarities to calculate, but this doesn't sound so bad for a modern computer. I don't understand why it should take a few hours to do that. And the set operation version, that should be quicker as far as I can tell, is actually much slower than `dist`. [Another package called `fingerprint` is supposed to deal with such cases more efficiently, but so far I haven't been able to make it work, it gives a lot of errors when trying to make what they call 'featvec' objects].

The other thing to consider is that the 2-5 features per object are not very repetitive. There may be a group of 100 or so objects with at least one feature in common between them, but then none of the other 12.9 K objects has any feature in common with these 100 objects. The consequence is that the pivoted feature matrix is very sparse (if we consider 0's as empty). There are about 4000 columns in the pivoted matrix, and each row has at most 5 1's. I wonder if this is negatively impacting the performance of `dist`, in that it has to multiply through a lot of 0's that could instead be ignored.

> Does it seem normal to you that it should take a few hours to apply `dist` to a matrix like the one I described? Can you suggest a different way to calculate the similarity that takes advantage of the sparseness of the matrix?

Anyway, I managed to get the output from `dist`, which however had class 'dist', and was a *distance* matrix, not a similarity one, so I had to use `1 - as.matrix(distance_matrix)` to be able to make the similarity matrix `apcluster` needs as input.

That's when I got the first 'memory' problem. R said the vector could not be allocated due to its size. I tried the usual tricks, but in the end I could not get more than 4 GB, and my matrices are (apparently) bigger.

I overcame this by assigning each time new matrices to their old 'self'.

And then when I submitted this painstakingly put together similarity matrix to `apcluster`, again the vector size error popped up, as if the first thing `apcluster` did was create some other large object from what I had fed it.

I had a look at `as.Sparse...` in `apcluster`, but it does not seem to help a lot, considering that you have to calculate the full matrix first anyway.

In the end the only thing that worked a little bit was 'leveraged affinity propagation' by `apclusterL`, which however is an approximation.

> Does anybody know if and how I could do this better? E.g. is it wise to pivot the data first, or should I stick to list and set operations? Or, can the fact that the initial matrix is sparse be used to compute directly a sparse *similarity* matrix, rather than compute it fully and reduce it to sparse later?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

BTW, yes, I saw this thread: [Cluster Analysis in R on large sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009078/cluster-analysis-in-r-on-large-sparse-matrix/21764342#21764342) ; which does not seem to have been answered conclusively.

Answer (score 1):

The R interpreter is really slow.

So you should use R mostly to "drive" your program, but implement all the computations heavy stuff in C or FORTRAN.

You didn't show the code you are using, but I guess it involves nested for loops? Try to rewrite it without any for loops in R, or rewrite it in C.

But no matter what, AP clustering will always remain very slow. It involves many passes over O(n²) matrixes, i.e. it scales very badly.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I found that my R studio was running the wrong version of R; I switched to the 64 bit version, with about 8 GB memory. It is now able to process my matrices. Still slow, but at least it doesn't crash and I don't need to use the leveraged method. I also found how to write a custom similarity matrix function that I can use directly in `apcluster`, without generating intermediate matrices. I will see if I can do the implementation you suggest.